# How to detect if my program is running in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, console

I am writing a C# console app. It's going to run as a scheduled task.

I want my EXE to exit quickly if it finds that another process is still running from the previous schedule task execution.

I can't seem to find the way to let my app detect the active processes, and so know whether it's already running or not.

Thanks for any ideas.
Peter

Comment: http://www.sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One very common technique is to create a mutex when your process starts. If you cannot create the mutex it means there is another instance running.

This is the sample from Nathan's Link:

```
//Declare a static Mutex in the main form or class...
private static Mutex _AppMutex = new Mutex(false, "MYAPP");

// Check the mutex before starting up another possible instance
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
  if (MyForm._AppMutex.WaitOne(0, false))
  {
    Application.Run(new MyForm());
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Application Already Running");
  }
  Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: Here is a link, perhaps tekBlues could update the answer with the code sample. http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/csharp/209938/209938/how-can-i-check-if-my-application-is-already-running/?S=B20000 NOTE: I haven't tested this sample.

Comment: A mutex is a better option than inspecting the processes because you may not have permissions to look through the processes but you dont have to worry about that w/ a mutex

Comment: If you're going to do this, you have to make 100% sure that your app can't lock up, or else you'll end up DOS'ing yourself

Answer (score 1):

try
System.Diagnostics.Process

getProcesses()

Answer (score 1):

Use a mutex:

```
// Allow only one instance of app
// See http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#one.application.instance
bool firstInstance;
_mutex = new Mutex(false, "Local\\[UniqueName]", out firstInstance);
```

[Link to reference in comment](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/faq/#one.application.instance)

Comment: Thanks, that was very simple!  (which is all I can handle at this point)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there something in System.Diagnostics for checking processes?

Edit: Do any of these links help you? I can see how they might be useful.

- [How to check if an application is running](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1541.htm)
- [Looping through all processes on the system](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=56380)

I'm sorry that all I can do is provide you links to other items. I've never had to use System.Diagnostics but hopefully it might help you or someone else out.